# Word that means that a thing can not be more or less itself

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In discussing Plato's *Phaedo*, I need to analyze Socrates's assertion that a soul can not be more or less of a soul. Is there a single word or phrase which expresses the notion is either a member of a class or not, and can not be more or less of a member?

Comment: Absolute, binary, Boolean...

Comment: I think I know what you mean. It's related to infinity: you can add to it, or subtract from it, the result will always be infinity. The word's got to be of Greek origin. I'll keep looking.

Comment: In the case of one specific class, the idea that you're either in that class or not is often expressed by [*You can't be **half** pregnant!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+can%27t+be+half+pregnant%22) On the other hand, you can certainly be [***heavily** pregnant*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22heavily+pregnant%22) if your "class membership credentials" are manifest to all. Pregnancy is [***a binary category.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+binary+category%22)

Comment: Actually, the word is "immutable."

Comment: @Ricky: *Immutable* means the state cannot change. Which is not the same thing as saying that *at any given point in time* the state must be one of two possible values (i.e. - it's never some "intermediate" value).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "He's immutably a member of that class" means he cannot be more ... or less ... a member of said class. What am I missing?

Comment: The term **classifying adjective** is used for those adjectives stating the class of a referent, the set to which it belongs: a French girl // nuclear / non-nuclear weapons // a weekly magazine // a geological survey.

Comment: Gah. I saw this question and thought that the idiom "A spade is a spade is a spade" would meet it. But single-word/phrase request means an idiom is unlikely to be appropriate. hey ho.

Comment: @Ricky "Immutable" isn't perfect – it's a little opaque, and I could see some people not immediately grasping what is meant – but I think it applies the best here that I've seen. I'll accept that as the answer if you submit it.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth That seems to fit the spirit of what I'm going for, but sadly isn't an adjective itself :P

Comment: *self-contained* meaning "having all that one (it) needs in oneself (itself)" *[OED]*

Answer (score 3):

**atomic**.  Originally in chemistry, and now used outside the physical sciences, it means the smallest part of a substance which retains the properties peculiar to the substance.  Now, we recognize some physical exceptions to this as it applies to the structure of matter, such as isotopes, and perhaps more generally, compounds.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **elemental**:

> of the nature of an ultimate constituent; simple; uncompounded. ([Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/elemental?s=t))

Or **ultimate**:

> incapable of further analysis, division, or separation ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ultimate))

Comment: You can add to elemental, and subtract from ultimate. "Immutable" is definitely the right word here.

Comment: @Ricky If you add to something elemental, it's no longer elemental.  If you subtract from something ultimate, it's no longer ultimate.  "Immutable" emphasizes the changelessness, not the state.

Comment: I beg to differ. You are correct in saying that adding to something elemental CHANGES it to something else. That which is immutable cannot be changed no matter how much you try to add to it or subtract from it. It's like the concept of infinity in math. Infinity + 7 = Infinity.